# Does size matter in case of attack on LUKS partition?

Tags: encryption, aes

Does the size of the LUKS partition affect the difficulty of a brute force attack, or would it not make difference? For example, would a 100MB partition be easier to attack than a 100GB partition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the size does not matter. No matter which algorithm you use, the attack with the best chance of success is to guess the passphrase, unless the passphrase is a long, random, unmemorizable one (i.e. a keyfile in practice).

Attacks against the passphrase are not helped by a larger amount of ciphertext. They work by generating the key corresponding to the passphrase, and then attempting to decrypt with the resulting key. A few bytes of ciphertext are enough to validate the guess.

If the algorithm is the limiting factor, then finding the 128-bit key using the fastest known techniques requires very close to $2^127$ attempts on average ($127$ and not $128$ because on average the key is found after exploring half the search space). Knowing a lot of plaintext-ciphertext pairs does not help to find the key or to decrypt other ciphertexts: cryptographic algorithms are designed to resist such attacks.

Comment: It's very good to hear. You were very clear. I plan to split the container file without fear. Thank you